# Why is OperationKey empty in my Polly retry policy?

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic

I'm using Polly version 7.1.1

I have a simple Polly retry policy that will retry an operation once if it fails with an `NpgsqlException`:

```
var policy = Policy
    .Handle<NpgsqlException>()
    .Retry(
        retryCount: 1,
        onRetry: (exception, retryCount, context) =>
        {
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, $"Retry {retryCount} of {context.OperationKey}, due to {exception.Message}", exception);
        })
    .WithPolicyKey("PostgresConnectionPolicy");
```

I have a method that attempts to connect to a PostgreSQL database and run a query using said policy:

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
{
    conn.Open()

    using(var command = GetCommand())
    {
        policy.Execute(
            action: context => command.ExecuteNonQuery(),
            contextData: new Context("Command.ExecuteNonQuery"));
    }
}
```

The method fails, gets retried, and the logger prints the following:

> Retry 1 of , due to 42P01: relation "myDatabase" does not exist

I would expect the following to be logged:

> Retry 1 of **Command.ExecuteNonQuery**, due to 42P01: relation "myDatabase" does not exist

Why is `OperationKey` empty when the policy logs the retry?

**EDIT:** Adding a simplified console application as an example.

This prints the following to the console:

```
Retry 1 of , due to Testing Polly
Error.
```

Example:

```
using Polly;
using System;

namespace TestPolly
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var policy = Policy
                .Handle<Exception>()
                .Retry(
                    retryCount: 1,
                    onRetry: (exception, retryCount, context) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Retry {retryCount} of {context.OperationKey}, due to {exception.Message}");
                    })
                .WithPolicyKey("PostgresConnectionPolicy");

            try
            {
                policy.Execute(
                    action: context => TestPolly(),
                    contextData: new Context("TestPolly"));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error.");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void TestPolly()
        {
            throw new Exception("Testing Polly");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Context object

- defines some [predefined fields](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/ffe99a34edd96d5c5c94075fe22aae8e1a7ed3ed/src/Polly/Context.cs) (like `OperationKey`, `PolicyKey`, `CorrelationId`)
- and it [implements](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/d95959fe1449407603c8605282fbba97041fd026/src/Polly/Context.Dictionary.cs) the `IDictionary<string, object>` interface to let the consumer provide any key-value pairs.

If you look at [this line of the source code](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/ffe99a34edd96d5c5c94075fe22aae8e1a7ed3ed/src/Polly/Context.cs#L20) or [the documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Keys-And-Context-Data) you can see that there is a constructor overload which accepts the `OperationKey`.

So you define your Execute call like this:

```cs
policy.Execute(
    action: context => command.ExecuteNonQuery(),
    contextData: new Context("Command.ExecuteNonQuery()"));
```

In my opinion it is a bit better approach since you are not relying on string-based key insertion and retrieval.

---

UPDATE: I've found the problem.

You have been using a wrong overload of `Execute`.

```cs
policy.Execute(
    action: context => command.ExecuteNonQuery(),
    context: new Context("Command.ExecuteNonQuery()"));
```

Use `context` instead of `contextData` and the `OperationKey` will present.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, as you can see in my question, but OperationKey is empty in the policy retry callback.

Comment: I've added a copy/paste example for you

Comment: @Marcus You are right. I've tried it with 7.x, 6.x and 5.x versions and all the time it was null. I haven't found any open or closed issue about this behaviour, but maybe you should raise one.

Comment: I will. Thanks though!

Comment: @Marcus I've found the problem. Your sample is using a wrong overload. Please use `context:` instead of `contextData:` and the `OperationKey` will present. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Got around this issue by using a custom context instead.

Policy:

```
var policy = Policy
            .Handle<NpgsqlException>()
            .Retry(
                retryCount: 1,
                onRetry: (exception, retryCount, context) =>
                {
                    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, $"Retry {retryCount} of {context["Operation"]}, due to {exception.Message}", exception);
                })
            .WithPolicyKey("PostgresConnectionPolicy");
```

Execute:

```
policy.Execute(
    action: context => command.ExecuteNonQuery(),
    contextData: new Context() { { "Operation", "Command.ExecuteNonQuery()" } });
```